# Was Princess Susannah in on it?

Tags: black-mirror, the-national-anthem

In "The National Anthem", the first episode of *Black Mirror*, Princess Susannah, dubbed "the Facebook Princess", is kidnapped, only to be released if the Prime Minister fulfils a rather bizarre and specific request.
A first video with the princess reading the demands from her kidnapper is posted to YouTube. When it looks as if the PM is trying to cheat on the demands, a severed finger along with a USB-stick containing a second video showing the finger being cut from the princess is delivered to a news station.

As it turns out,

> the finger did not belong to the princess and the kidnapper had already released her half an hour before his demands were met.

While the first video released could be made with or without compliance from the princess, the second one

> needs her acting as if in sudden pain.

**Therefore, was she in on her own kidnapping?**

Besides being a darling of the (online) media, she also seemed to be somewhat of an activist.

Did any of the creators of the show ever comment on this? Are there clues in the episode itself?

Comment: “the second one needs her acting as if in sudden pain” — there are, of course, ways to achieve that other than removing her thumb.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure she's not acting. There are several ways to create sudden pain.
It's true she is very popular, and might be an activist on some causes, but as we can see at the end

> this a weird artist performance, and not a political, terrorist or activist action.

Answer (score -2):

It's possible, but it's also possible that she was just instructed to pretend that her finger was being cut off

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on your answer, if it's possible why was it possible she was in on it, if it wasn't why not? Why do you think she may have been instructed to pretend that her finger was being cut off and why would she have followed said instruction if she was kidnapped?

Comment: @Edlothiad:   I don't see what additional elaboration is necessary.   If the kidnapper can force her to read the statement under threat of death, he can also get her to act any way he demands.